# Compare and get the new data inserted into table based on month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have FM_TBL table which has month_id column which is number data type and dates are stored in this in format 'YYYYMM'.

I want to compare the data from previous month and current month and based on this find out the number of new rows inserted into FM_TABLE in the current month.

Comment: update your question and show the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a minus

```
select SYS_DB_NAME, ENTITY_ID, MONTH_ID
from my_table 
where MONTH_ID = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad( extract(month from sysdate), 2,'0')
minus  
select  SYS_DB_NAME, ENTITY_ID, MONTH_ID
from my_table 
where MONTH_ID = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad( (extract(month from sysdate) -1) , 2,'0')
```

and if you need  the rows  content

```
select * from  my_table  m
inner join  (
    select SYS_DB_NAME, ENTITY_ID, MONTH_ID
    from my_table 
    where MONTH_ID = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad( extract(month from sysdate), 2,'0')
    minus  
    select  SYS_DB_NAME, ENTITY_ID, MONTH_ID
    from my_table 
    where MONTH_ID = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad( (extract(month from sysdate) -1) , 2,'0')
) T on m.SYS_DB_NAME = t.SYS_DB_NAME 
      AND m.ENTITY_ID = t.ENTITY_ID 
        AND m.MONTH_ID = t.MONTH_ID
```

and if you need  only count

```
select count(*) from  
inner join  (
    select SYS_DB_NAME, ENTITY_ID, MONTH_ID
    from my_table 
    where MONTH_ID = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad( extract(month from sysdate), 2,'0')
    minus  
    select  SYS_DB_NAME, ENTITY_ID, MONTH_ID
    from my_table 
    where MONTH_ID = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad( (extract(month from sysdate) -1) , 2,'0')
) T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select count(*)
from fm_tbl t
where t.monthid = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM') and
      not exists (select 1
                  from fm_tbl t2
                  where t2.monthid = to_char(sysdate - interval '1' month, 'YYYYMM') and
                        t2.cust_srcid = t.cust_srcid
                 );
```

If customers can be repeated in a given month, then use `count(distinct cust_srcid)`.

Comment: Sorry i need further modification in query which i have updated in question.. I also want to check if the number of newly inserted rows not in between -10 and 10 then i want to see only those rows..