# Compare and get the new data inserted into table based on month and threshold defined

Tags: sql, oracle

I have `FM_TBL` table which has month_id column which is number data type and dates are stored in this in format 'YYYYMM'.

I want to compare the data from previous month and current month and based on this find out the number of new rows inserted into `FM_TABLE` in the current month.

And i want to see only the number of rows for which the difference is not in between -10 and 10.

For e.g if i use: `ROUND (100 * ( (num_rows - num_rows_prev) / num_rows), 2) diff_pct`

and in `WHERE` condition if I can put `diff_pct not between -10 and 10`

then I can get only the number of rows which are newly inserted in current month and number of rows not in between -10 and 10.

Useful link: [Compare and get the new data inserted into table based on month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199771/compare-and-get-the-new-data-inserted-into-table-based-on-month/52199997?noredirect=1#comment91349503_52199997)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have below query which is comparing the number of rows from previous month and current month and return the result if there is new number of rows adding in FM_TBL table and the threshold of the new number of rows is not in between percentage -10 and 2.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Now i want to create new query for FM_TBL table which should give me those number of DIFF rows from the result which i can see from above query.

Comment: You mean  the difference of number of rows  between the two month ..query ?

Comment: The question is not clear  ..  you should update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..  please

Comment: yes the difference between number of rows

Comment: and if the difference between two months  is > (abs(10%) )  you want the rows  list  otherwise not ?

Comment: yes exactly if its above 10% i want those rows list otherwise not

Comment: ok  ...but the difference of 10%  respect what ??? the totale of the rows in table ?  .. the previuos month result ?   .. is not clear to me  (anyway  can't be  -10)

Comment: i mean if the percentage of newly inserted rows in FM_TABLE is above 10% for current month then i want only those rows to appear

Comment: i have posted  an aswer  hope is what you are looking  for  ..

Comment: You've shown 23 out of 150 rows (as an image; please post text!); the first and last look like outliers, and the from the rest each of the three months has the same number of entries. So what output are you expecting for that data? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

should  be  a select for the rows  where exist the condition  for not in abs(10% )

```
select * from  my_table  m
inner join  (
    select SYS_DB_NAME, ENTITY_ID, MONTH_ID
    from my_table 
    where MONTH_ID =  to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad( extract(month from sysdate), 2,'0')
    minus  
    select  SYS_DB_NAME, ENTITY_ID, MONTH_ID
    from my_table 
    where MONTH_ID =  to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad(( extract(month from sysdate) -1) , 2,'0') 
) T on m.SYS_DB_NAME = t.SYS_DB_NAME 
      AND m.ENTITY_ID = t.ENTITY_ID 
        AND m.MONTH_ID = t.MONTH_ID 
where exists (
   select t1.tot_act_month
         , t2.tot_prev_month
        , abs(100*((t1.tot_act_month -t2.tot_prev_month)/t2.tot_prev_month)) rate 
        from  (
        select count(*) tot_act_month
        from my_table 
        where MONTH_ID =  to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad( extract(month from sysdate), 2,'0') 
        ) t1 
        cross join  (
        select count(*) tot_prev_month
        from my_table 
        where MONTH_ID =  to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad( extract(month from sysdate), 2,'0') 
        ) t2 
        where abs(100*((t1.tot_act_month -t2.tot_prev_month)/t2.tot_prev_month))  <= 10.0 
)
```

Comment: Your `year()` and `month()` calls aren't Oracle syntax... guess you mean `to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM')` and `to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'YYYYMM')` (with that second one in `t2` as well)? You're missing a space before in `whereabs(...)` too. I'm not even sure it's supposed to be based on sysdate - unclear what 'current month' means in the question, and the sample data is unhelpful too (since there is nothing for this or last month anyway, and the months that are shown have the same counts). But this still ought to be useful to the OP and give them some pointers at least...

Comment: i am getting error invalid identifier as 'MONTH' at line  where MONTH_ID = year(sysdate) || lpad(month(sysdate), 2,'0')

Comment: @Andrew   .. have you tested  the previous  query (the query in the prevoisu answer)  or not  .  ..? have you executed ?

Comment: @AlexPoole  ..  correct  .. wrong  ..Oracle doc reference  .. some minutes for change the code  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge - I was tempted to edit it for you instead of commenting, but that seemed a bit extreme, even veering towards not matching author's intent; and some people get upset by that sort of thing *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole  ..
do not worry a few minutes and fix everything ... thanks a lot for the suggestion ..

Comment: in minus statement its giving missing right parenthesis.... where MONTH_ID =  to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad( extract(month from sysdate) -1) , 2,'0')

Comment: I still think you'd be better off with a single `to_char()`; not least as in January, `to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') || lpad(( extract(month from sysdate) -1) , 2,'0')` would have given you `201800`? Using `to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'YYYYMM')` would give you `201712`. (Also your `t2` filter still needs to have the -1, either way?)

Comment: i am not getting expected data when i try to manipulate with the MONTH and where abs(100*((t1.tot_act_month -t2.tot_prev_month)/t2.tot_prev_month))  <= 10.0

Comment: I just want to to get only those number of rows which are newly inserted in current month and those number of rows not in between percentage -10 and 10

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this:

```
select * 
  from (
    select fm.*, 
           count(1) over (partition by cust_srcid) cid, 
           count(case when month_id = m1 then 1 end) over () c1,
           count(case when month_id = m2 then 1 end) over () c2
      from fm_tbl fm 
      join (select 201806 m1, 201805 m2 from dual) m on month_id in (m1, m2))
  where cid < 2 and abs((c1-c2)/c2) > .1
```

**<sup>[working demo built on your sample data](http://rextester.com/BIRXI88162)</sup>**

How does it work?

- in column `CID` we are counting how many times same `ID` appears in compared months,
- `C1` counts rows for first month, `C2` for second,
- subquery `m` is where I put compared months. You could use `sysdate` to make it universal, I did it for testing purposes,
- final `where` filters only rows which were in one month (current or previous) but not in both; also we show result only when row counts (`c1` and `c2`)for each month differs by more than 10%.

I only used `count` in analytic version, please read documentation and examples if you don't know it. And if you want subquery based on sysdate change to:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM') as m1, 
       to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'YYYYMM') as m2 
  from dual
```

Comment: i think still the results are generating lit bit different. I have updated my question and added what i am expecting from the results. Can you please check that ?